# sum up value in all subdocument in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to sum up the value of a field in a subdocument but I get getting 0 are my summation.

Here is the DB.

```
[

  {
    "card": "master",
    "payment": [
      {
        "amount": 220,
        "status": "paid"
      },
      {
        "amount": 100,
        "status": "paid"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "card": "master",
    "payment": [
      {
        "amount": 100,
        "status": "paid"
      },
      {
        "amount": 130,
        "status": "paid"
      }
    ],
  },
]
```

Here is my aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      card: "master",
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      amount: {
        $sum: "$payment.amount"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

The response

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "amount": 0
  }
]
```

I expect the amount to be 550 and not 0. Please what is wrong with my aggregation.

Comment: You can do it by including a [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage before the `$group` stage.

Comment: Should there be a field named `interest` in there?

Comment: @Joe Thanks i corrected it to payment. @prasad_ thanks `$unwind` worked